# Not able to select a dropdown value using selenium webdriver(Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have no idea what is wrong in the simple code i have written to select a value from the dropdown. I have been watching other tutorials and code samples and i dont find any mistake in my code. Could someone please help me? I have tried running my code in Chrome as well as Mozilla(on two different OS) but still the issue exists.I am posting attachment of the html as well as selenium code.
Also, i am sure the problem is not because i have used wait because even if i comment that line or use it after loading the web page, the issue is there.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDTvw.png)

[Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bweQL.png)

Comment: What do you mean still the issue exists?? Is there any exception??

Comment: the code looks fine,can you post what error you are getting when running the code

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown value is not getting selected. The code runs fine. I am not getting any error or exception but the value does not get selected in dropdown.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry, the value gets selected in chrome but not in mozilla. Any guesses why?

Comment: What version of Mozilla and selenium are you using??

Comment: Selenium version 3.0 beta and firefox version is 48

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try **clicking on the dropdown** and then selecting the value.

```
tp.click();
```

and then

```
Select dropdown = new Select(tp);
dropdown.selectByValue("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("custtitle"))).selectByValue("2");
```

OR

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("custtitle"))).selectByVisibleText("Mrs.");
```